# Typecast bytes in powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, casting, byte

In C, I have the following code

```
struct _file_header* file_header = (struct _file_header*)(cfg_bytes + (cfg_size - 16));
```

Which effectively fills the `_file_header` structure with the bytes from memory. I want to do the same thing in Powershell, but I am confused with the `[System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes` returning some bytes that aren't related to the data I see in `cfg_bytes`

Take the following PowerShell code,

```
$cfg_bytes   = (Get-Content $env:ProgramData'\config.bin' -Raw)
$cfg_size    = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCI.GetByteCount($cfg_bytes)
$file_header = $cfg_bytes.Substring($cfg_size - 16, 16)
```

When I `Write-Output [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($file_header)`, the output is not the same as I see from my debugger memory viewer. How can I obtain the bytes in the same format as the C example, such that I'd be able to read the same structure in PowerShell?

Comment: Is the file encoded with the same encoding you're using to get it's bytes? You can also use `Get-Content -Encoding Byte...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon)
 suggests, use the following to directly get a file's *raw bytes* in PowerShell:

- In *Windows PowerShell*:

```
$cfg_bytes = Get-Content -Encoding Byte -Raw $env:ProgramData\config.bin
```

- In *PowerShell (Core) 7+*:

```
$cfg_bytes = Get-Content -AsByteStream -Raw $env:ProgramData\config.bin
```

<sup>Note: This breaking change in syntax between the two PowerShell editions is unfortunate, and arguably should never have happened - see [GitHub issue #7986](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7986).</sup>

Note that adding `-Raw` to the [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) call - when combined with `-Encoding Byte` / `-AsByteStream` - efficiently returns all bytes *as a single array*, strongly typed as `[byte[]]`.

Without `-Raw`, the bytes would be *streamed* - i.e., output to the pipeline *one by one* - which, if the output isn't accumulated, keeps memory use constant - but is much slower.